# This puts out Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

So im working on a ctf right now, that basically forces me to do something in C. It's a basic program that checks if the output of the check_password function equals the hashcode. I decided to bruteforce this, so I wrote some code. There's probably some easier way to do this, put I wanna test my coding skills a little and maybe learn a little bit more about C along the way. So I wrote this code that increments the argument given to the check_password function, each loop by 1, and then have it compare the output to the hashcode. When I run this it throws an "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.

I already tried googling the problem, but I didnt seem to understand what the specific error in my code was.  Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
unsigned long hashcode = 0x21DD09EC;
unsigned long check_password(const char* p){
        int* ip = (int*)p;
        int i;
        int res=0;
        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                res += ip[i];
        }
        return res;
}

int main()
{
    const char* i = 0;
    long current_guess;
    bool found = false;
    while(!found) {
        current_guess = check_password(i);
        if(current_guess == hashcode) {
            printf(i);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So it should run through all the options, and print out i once it's done, except it throws the error. Help would be appreciated.

Here's the code of the program im trying to get the passcode too btw

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
unsigned long hashcode = 0x21DD09EC;
unsigned long check_password(const char* p){
        int* ip = (int*)p;
        int i;
        int res=0;
        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                res += ip[i];
        }
        return res;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        if(argc<2){
                printf("usage : %s [passcode]\n", argv[0]);
                return 0;
        }
        if(strlen(argv[1]) != 20){
                printf("passcode length should be 20 bytes\n");
                return 0;
        }

        if(hashcode == check_password( argv[1] )){
                system("/bin/cat flag");
                return 0;
        }
        else
                printf("wrong passcode.\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `const char* i = 0;` then `i++`... later `(int*)p;` can you explain how this works? Why not use `unsigned long` instead of `const char *`? `ip[i];` won't work for indexing into an `int`--use modulus to iterate over the numbers. Are you trying to sum the digits? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. Im using const char* i = 0 because the check_password function takes in a const char* as a parameter and im passing it the i. Cant explain the (int*)p part since thats not my code, i just copied it out of the C program of the challenge and thought I could guess it with this. Gonna look into modulus. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, my original answer was not the answer you wanted. Now that you've clarified:

The `check_password` function does something 'a bit naughty' in casting a `const char*` pointer to an `int*` pointer, but that's OK. It needs at least 20 chars, so that the string can be 'interpreted' as an array of 5 integers.

When you call this function, you need to pass it a character string (of at least 20 chars). In the `main` example you have shown, this string is `argv[1]`, which is the first parameter given to the program *after* its name; so, if you run the program with "checkpw ABCD1234WXYZ5678aaaa" then the ABC... string will be the data passed to the function.

Does this help?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. After I did what you said, it now throws just a segmentation fault. Any idea why this happens? :/

Comment: @Darki  See edit! But maybe you can clarify what it is you're trying to actually check?

Comment: im starting to get a little bit confused, can you take a look at my edit? I added the code of the program im trying to get the passcode from, maybe that will clear things up a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're passing i as a pointer, and then dereference it. So you will dereference 0x1, an address which you're not supposed to access, and get a SIGSEGV.

Plus, not exactly sure what you're trying to do with this program. The function check password is trying to access an int as an array, that makes no sense.

Edit:
With the complete code it makes much more sense.
What the program is doing is the following:
Takes the first argument (argv[1]), if it's len is 20 (aka if the argument is a 20 characters string), then it will be passed to the function check_password.
Now, here you need a pretty good knowledge of C to understand what is happening.

The pointer to your string, a char const *, is now casted as a pointer to an int.
A character is always one byte. An int is usually 4 bytes. Your string of characters will now be read as an array of int.

Let's take the string "test".
It is encoded in memory in the following way: `0x74(t) 0x73(s) 0x65(e) 0x74(t)`
You will notice it's reversed. That is because most computers nowadays are little endian (ie the biggest bit is read first).
When that string is cast as an int, and access, it will read as an int of value `0x74736574`, aka 1953719668.

The check password is iterating over this array of int 5 times. It will add the first 5 integers it's reading, which means if we take the following password: `abcdefghijklmnopqrst`, the result will be the following:

```
first loop:
res = 0x64636261
second loop:
res += 0x68676665
third loop:
res += 0x72717069
fourth loop:
res += 0x76757473
last loop:
res += 0x7a797877
```

Your goal is to reached the value 0x21DD09EC with the password. One of the many possible answers would be:
`0fwzzzgzabafgccczc9c`

Comment: the function check_password is not mine, i copied it out of the program which im trying to get the password to for the ctf. Any idea how I could fix the i as a pointer thing. Pretty new to C :/

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I didnt know the challenge had something to do with C, but I really wanted to solve it anyway. Thanks for the help :) Guess i'll have to look into it another time

Comment: Edited my answer as you submitted the original source code. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you try to achieve, but

```
const char* i = 0;
```

i is a pointer point to address 0, that could be the cause for the segmentation fault. You can try assign the pointer to your input first before using the pointer.

```
const char input[10];

i = input;
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I think I kinda get it now, but noob question: how do I increment the input by 1 just like I did with the i++?

Comment: It depends on the type of the pointer, if it is a char*, i++ will increment the size of a char which is 1byte, but for int*, size of a int mostly is 4 bytes.

Comment: Imagine a char array, char[8] input = {0x0,0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5,0x6,0x7}; for char* i, i[0] = 0x0, and i[1] = 1. for int* i, i[0] = 0x123, i[1] = 0x4567

Comment: umm, i guess i took on a little bit too much. definetely gonna learn some proper C before attempting challenges like this first. Thanks for the help anyways :)